# PHP variable update (live)

Tags: php, jquery, database, variables

I have a variable that gets updated on a submit

```
$newenergy = $energy - 10;

$result = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET energy='$newenergy' WHERE id='".$_SESSION['user_id']."'")
or die(mysql_error());
```

on the next page if i echo out the variable from the database energy it i will say the old variable still until i refresh the page again is there a way of easily getting round this or will i have to use jquery and if so how do i go about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

From how I understood your question, you currently have a code like this (partly pseudo-code):

```
$energyQuery = mysql_query(/** ... querying for current energy value **/);
$energy = $energyQuery->fetch("energy");

if (isSubmit()) {
    $newEnergy = $energy - 10;
    mysql_query(/** Update energy to $newEnergy i database **/);
}

echo $energy;
```

And now you're wondering why the `echo` in the last line prints out the old value; and only after refreshing the page again, it displays the updated one - am I correct?

Well an easy way to fix that would be to not create a `$newEnergy` variable but simply to override the `$energy` variable (as long as you don't need the original energy value after that update anymore).

```
$energy = $energy - 10; //Or simply: $energy -= 10;
```

Comment: But say for example I have another page that gets the variables and then I actually need the variable as it is without editing it is there a way of getting in after it has been updated?

Comment: Do you mean you are updating the `$energy` on `PageA` and display it on `PageB`, but want to notify `PageB` about changes from `PageA` without refreshing it?

Comment: Yes something like that basically I would like it to be sort of live updating so if it gets changed in the database it would display it's new variable

Comment: In this case you should use JavaScript  `WebSockets`. This way you can send update notifications to clients whenever an important value is updated on your server. There are plenty tutorials on the internet about it :)